# facebook like button not showing in webview (ios and android)

Tags: javascript, facebook, html, uiwebview, webview

I have a simple application that runs an html file in a webview. When I run it in android browser or in iphone browser safari, I'm able to see the facebook like button.

But when it comes to the webviews in both platforms the like button doesn't show.

**my html file**

```
.
.
.
<body>

    <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
.
.
.
```

**my javascript file**

```
this.getItems().items[0].setHtml('<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://test.com" data-send="true" data-layout="button_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resolved when i added `https:` to `//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1`

Answer (score 0):

They are having an outage http://connect.facebook.net/en_us/all.js

Answer (score 0):

From https://developers.facebook.com/live_status/

connect.facebook.net issues
today at 8:30pm

We are currently seeing issues with users connecting to connect.facebook.net. This is resulting in the JS SDK not loading correctly. We are aware of the problem and are working to resolve this.